# Alexa Skills - Editing existing live skill in VS Code

Tags: edit, alexa-skills-kit, live

I started developing skills for Alexa some time ago. I managed to add one skill to the Alexa Skills Store. Now I would like to make some changes in my code, but I don't want these changes to be deployed in my skill right away. I want them to be deployed on my 'test version'. When that test version works like I want it to, I want that verstion to be deployed as a live skill. It is very easy to do that job in Alexa Developer Console, but I didn't find any solution how to do it in Visual Studio Code. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hosted Skill in Alexa Developer Console:

1. Install [ASK CLI](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html)
2. Run `ask deploy` (the code will only be deploy to the dev env and be in prod after you publish the new version)

Hosted Skill yourself:

1. You have to change the endpoint of your skill in your DEV env.
2. You can then programmatically upload the code to your lambda (or other backend)